# How to know the external ip address of my gateway?

Tags: networking, ip

In my office network i unknowingly changed a setting of my gateway of lan network .. I had set my phone's ip address under a section in setting which states that.. Only this ip can login to the network.. And the ip which i filled in was of my phone which is connected to my office wifi network..
Due to this reason none of the computer in the lan network can access the router's login page.. 
I had used the gui interface.. 
So now i need to know my lan's router external ip address..  So thar i can access the router login page on my phone

Answer (score 0):

If your phone was connected to your office wifi network, the IP address of your phone will have been a [private IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network). e.g. one in the range of either

- 10.0.0.0/8
- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16

The third option is most common, with a /24 range.

Therefore you'll need to be connected to the office wifi network, and have the same private IP as you originally set in order to connect. If your DHCP lease has reset, you may have to manually set and try each host in your phone's network configuration (e.g. 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, etc). Failing that, a reset of your router using the physical reset button will have to suffice.

If you really do need the external WAN address, then making a Google query from a network machine will do that: [IP query](https://google.com/search?q=ip).